# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "testdb" failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "katie"

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

1. I logged into PostgreSQL: `psql -U postgres`
2. Created 'testdb': `CREATE DATABASE testdb;`
3. Logged out: `\q`,
4. Logged into 'testdb': `psql -d testdb -U postgres`
5. Created some tables and sequences in 'testdb'
6. Did: `pg_dump: pg_dump testdb --no-owner`

and got this:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "testdb" failed: 
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "katie"
```

My pg_hba.conf file:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "krb5", "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.




# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                password

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

How to fix it that I would be able to do `pg_dump`?

Comment: Have you created the user "katie" in the database? And given that user a password? Or did you intend to dump as the `postgres` user using `pg_dump -U postgres ....` ? To list users: `\du` .

Comment: @Craig Ringer: yup, I created user 'katie' and gave her a password. I wanted to do this: `pg_dump: pg_dump testdb --no-owner` I cant' use `-U postgres` option 'cause I want to use `--no-owner`

Comment: You can run `pg_dump` as a database superuser and use the `--no-owner` switch -- that switch just prevents `pg_dump` from adding statements to the output which will set the owner when the script is run. On the other hand, it's not clear why the password for katie failed. Did you get a password prompt when you ran `pg_dump`? Were you typing that command directly on a command line, or using some scheduler?

Comment: @kgrittn: Ok, I logged as postgres: `katie@computer:~$ psql -U postgres` and ran command: `postgres-#  pg_dump testdb --no-owner -f /home/katie/Desktop/backup.sql;` but nothing happend and in `/home/katie/Desktop/` theres no such file like `backup.sql` ... I typed command on Kubuntu's terminal.

Comment: `pg_dump` is an executable that you run from the OS level, not a command or function that you run inside of `psql`.

Comment: @kgrittn: so I should use `katie@computer:~$ pg_dump testdb -U postgres --no-owner -f backup.sql` instead? But such command gives ownership to postgres (in my *.sql file) so its not like what I wanted at all ... I need to use `--no-owner`

Comment: When I run the equivalent, there is no ownership set in the file output from pg_dump, so ownership on restore is with whatever role was active when the file was *applied*, just like the documentation says. Can you show the statements from `backup.sql` that you think are setting ownership in some other way?

Comment: @kgrittn: OK its finally working good:) I ran command `katie@computer:~$ pg_dump testdb -U postgres --no-owner -f backup.sql` and its ok. I have no idea why earlier it wasnt good... Anyway, thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when the user exists and password authentication fails.  The reason this might work at one point but not another is that maybe the password was typed incorrectly, the password had been changed, or there was a bad password in the pg_hba.conf.  Generally speaking, resolve things by checking those causes in that order.

One option you have if you want to run these locally on the same computer is to set to ident (in 9.1 or lower) or peer (9.2 or higher) for local connections for a specific user, and then log in with the user of the same username.  This will use the OS process owner as the authentication check and bypass the need for password authentication.

One other comment on the pg_hba.conf is that it is generally a bad practice to use 'password' authentication.  Change that to either ident (or peer if 9.2 or higher) or md5.  The password option is old and deprecated and it sends the password needlessly in the clear over the socket.